# How to display various info text in viewport

Tags: scripting

How to display various and custom info text in viewport with script and clean with another script and /or shortcut in blender 2.8+(im using 2.9).

SCRIPT FOR DISPLAY

```
import bpy
import blf


class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self, context, prop):
        self.prop = prop
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
                   self.draw_text_callback,(context,),
                   'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

    def draw_text_callback(self, context):
        font_id = 0  # XXX, need to find out how best to get this.

        # draw some text
        blf.position(font_id, 15, 50, 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)
        blf.draw(font_id, "%s %s" % (context.scene.name, self.prop))

    def remove_handle(self):
         bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')

context = bpy.context             
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dns["dc"] = DrawingClass(context, "Draw This On Screen")
```

SCRIPT FOR CANCEL TEXT DRAW

```
import bpy
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dc = dns.get("dc")
dc.remove_handle()
```

Comment: Hi! Bare minimum is to show some effort (research, code, minimal example etc.). Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135123/display-text-on-3d-viewport

Comment: need the clear script. in this question and other ther'arent the script for clear in 2.8+

Comment: Please take your time and try to explain *in detail*: what you got and what you'd like to achieve *by editing your question*.

Comment: @batFINGER The question this is marked as duplicate of may have a duplicate *answer*, but it is not a duplicate *question*.

Comment: @RayMairlot  It's good enough AFAIC.   OP deleted prior question after it was marked as a dupe of question their illustration came from re centering text on screen. .  Hence OP is aware of code to write text on screen. If OP can explain why the answer to question marked as dupe doesn't work for them yeah perhaps re-open.   At the moment it shows very little effort (the other close vote above) .  Will attempt to hunt down a better dupe.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't think we should be closing questions based on what an OP has demonstrated they know in other questions. If other people come across this question and get directed to the duplicate I don't think they will find the answer explanatory enough of *this* problem.

Comment: @RayMairlot  Somehow (due to me too) original dupe comes from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135123/display-text-on-3d-viewport  chose to cut out middle man.  The second one re middle of the viewport is the OP's previous question (self removed) after marked dupe One I perhaps could have used as primary dupe again.   Do we need a question for bottom left, top left, slightly left of center, there is one re using 3d coords.

Comment: @batFINGER It's certainly getting a bit confusing, I would say [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38681/getting-area-region-view2d-pixel-coordinates-of-2d-views-vse-nla) (again, duplicate answer, not question) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75612/how-do-you-remove-a-draw-handler-after-its-been-added) are not good duplicates, the other two are.

Comment: @batFINGER I don't think different alignments requires different questions as those *would* be very similar. Would suggest just adding other alignment options to brockman's answer (if you or brockman have time) and maybe edit the question to something more general like "How do I align modal draw text in the viewport?" so it is not focused  on 'middle'. Thoughts?

Comment: you have a method for cancel text after few seconds?

Comment: Good approach... What's wrong with that?

Comment: We should re-discuss that for python questions specifically. If you look around, python q/a got usually less votes but answering is much more labor intensive than 95% of all the non-python answers (like instructions how to press 3 buttons). To prevent re-iterating the same thing over and over again and also to respect the effort of the original authors -> updating the old answers *and* closing when the answer nails it or the OP shows no effort is the way to go IMO @RayMairlot